# 6 shirts, 4 pants, 7 scarves, choosing randomly and then probability of picking red shirt and blue scarf?

Tags: probability, combinations

If I have 6 different color shirts (red, green, blue, yellow, white, black), 4 different color pants (blue, brown, black, grey) and 7 different color scarves (red, green, blue, yellow, white, black, purple) and then I randomly choose 4 shirts, 2 pants and 3 scarves (no repetition, order doesn't matter) from this set. Then, what is the probability that I would get a red shirt and blue scarf? I think the total amount of combinations would be $\dbinom{6}{4} * \dbinom{4}{2} * \dbinom{7}{3}  $ but don't know where to go from there.

Comment: You found the total correctly. Now find the number of possible combinations under the restriction that a red skirt is among the shirts and a blue scarf is among the scarfs. Think of it as taking a red skirt and a blue scarf apart as first move.

Answer (score 1):

To count the favorable cases, observe that if you select a red shirt and a blue scarf among the four selected shirts, two selected pants, and three selected scarves, you must select three of the other five available shirts, two of the four available pants, and two of the other six available scarves.  Therefore, the number of favorable cases is

> $$\binom{5}{3}\binom{4}{2}\binom{6}{2}$$

Hence, the probability of selecting a red shirt and a blue scarf when four shirts, two pants, and three scarves are chosen from six different color shirts, four different color pants, and seven different color scarves is

> $$\frac{\dbinom{5}{3}\dbinom{4}{2}\dbinom{6}{2}}{\dbinom{6}{4}\dbinom{4}{2}\dbinom{7}{3}}$$

Answer (score 0):

The probability of choosing a red shirt and blue scarf is the total number of combinations which have a red shirt and blue scarf divided by the total number of combinations, right?

You have the total. Now how do you get the total number of combinations that include a red shirt and blue scarf?

hint: try to count all the combinations which include a red shirt and a blue scarf.

spoiler: Think of it as instead of choosing 4 shirt colors (like when you did 6 choose 4) you can only choose 1.